# Is there ArcGIS Symbol Library PDF for ArcGIS Desktop i.e. index for symbols/line weights?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology

ESRI has an [old set of PDFs](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/product-documentation/view/productid/43/metaid/854) from 2004 showing all the symbols available in ArcGIS at the time and their names. I don't need it often but if I'm searching for a certain symbol and don't know its name it's sometimes easier to look at a few sheets of paper than to use the Symbol Selector. It doesn't seem like it's been updated for ArcGIS 10, though. I was wondering if anyone is aware of a new version of this, or if anyone has created one on their own they might be willing to share.

Comment: If you havn't found it yet I can email you a zipped file of all symbology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no.  I just saw a [blog on the mapping center](http://mappingcentre.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=home.rssFeed&ajaxOn=true) a week or two ago.
They are working on version 10 now.
Here is a [9.3v](http://downloads2.esri.com/MappingCenter2007/arcGISResources/more/ArcGIS_v93_Styles.PDF) PDF.

**EDIT:**
another location for symbol sets on the mapping center.
[resources center](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=arcgisResources.gateway)

Comment: 1500+ pages, that's going to be a pretty penny to print!

Answer (score 2):

Matt are you looking for Symbols to Print from ArcGIS 10?

[image]

[**http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=arcgisResources.gateway**](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=arcgisResources.gateway)

Credit to Brad Nesom on GIS Stack Exchange 
[Is there ArcGIS Symbol Library PDF for ArcGIS Desktop i.e. index for symbols/line weights?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18489/is-there-a-version-of-the-esri-arcgis-symbol-library-pdf-for-arcgis-10-or-some)

Comment: Those are extra downloadable styles, ones that aren't shipped with Arcgis. I'm looking for a printable document (or means to create one) of the as-shipped styles to use for quick reference and means of selection. My question is the same as the linked one, they could be merged.

Answer (score 1):

This is not current but its a start: http://downloads2.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/Utilities.pdf

Comment: Ooh, that looks really helpful! Do you know if there are similar PDFs for the other style references?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Answer to summarise what is in the PDF file that you have linked to?