# Printing out all symbols of a self created style file in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, style

I need an overview of all symbols I saved in a self created style file. Maybe in form of a list, to see the symbol itself and the name of the symbol.
Is there a way to export/create such an overview?

I am not looking for a [print out of the pre-prepared ArcMap symbols](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18489/is-there-arcgis-symbol-library-pdf-for-arcgis-desktop-i-e-index-for-symbols-lin).

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

I found an old extension for 9.3 called [Styledump](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/Cartography/Styles/Style_Dump/a06be6ca-0d38-4bbd-a20a-40331fd61527.htm), but which is sadly [not working in 10.x](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/printable-esri-symbol-sets-a-k-a-style-references).

Comment: maybe you will get it faster with an ArcPy script

Comment: I did not know, that you can access *.style-files with arcpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At ArcGIS.com there is a [Style Dump for ArcGIS 10.x](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0baef969273f4dc28e0c6ed167571748) addin:

This add-in provides functionality originally available in the [StyleDump Sample for 9.x](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/cartography/styles/style_dump/a06be6ca-0d38-4bbd-a20a-40331fd61527.htm). It has been ported to work with version 10.0 and beyond.